# Google Sheets: Conditional formatting based on another cell's style

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a select list in Google Sheet based on cells in another sheet. Those cells contains all the values that my list should display.

It works well but I also want to retrieve the style of those cells along with the values. So in my main sheet, depending on the selected value the style is copied from the "source" cells.

I know I can setup a conditional formatting so if the value is X or Y or Z I can apply a style but since my "source" cells are going to be updated, I'll have to also update those conditions which is a slow process.

I am wondering if there is a way to just dynamically copy the style of another cell.

Here is an example of my source cells:

[image]

Comment: How are you currently creating the "select list"? Is it a Data Validation? Could you please share a sanitized copy of the spreadsheet you are working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Apps Script, you could create an [onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) to do the following:

- Track changes to the cells that contain data validations based on values in a range.
- If the edited cell contains this data validation, look for the value in the source range that corresponds to the selected value.
- Copy and paste the format of the cell in source range to the selected cell.

To do that, just create a bound script by selecting **Tools > Script editor**, copy the following code and save the project.

#### Code sample (check comments):

```js
const onEdit = e => {
  // Get information on edited cell (column, row, value):
  const range = e.range;
  const column = range.getColumn();
  const row = range.getRow();
  const value = range.getValue();
  // Check that edited cell contains a validation rule and that its criteria type is "VALUE_IN_RANGE":
  const validation = range.getDataValidation();  
  if (validation && validation.getCriteriaType() == "VALUE_IN_RANGE") {
    const sourceRange = validation.getCriteriaValues()[0]; // Get range validation is based on
    // In source range, get index of the cell that corresponds to selected value in edited cell:
    const values = sourceRange.getValues();
    let i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      j = values[i].indexOf(value);
      if (j != -1) break;      
    }    
    const rangeToCopy = sourceRange.getSheet().getRange(sourceRange.getRow() + i, sourceRange.getColumn() + j); // Get cell in source range to copy format
    rangeToCopy.copyFormatToRange(range.getSheet(), column, column, row, row); // Copy format to edited cell
  }
}
```

[image]

#### Reference:

- [onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
- [Class DataValidation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation)
- [copyFormatToRange(sheet, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyformattorangesheet,-column,-columnend,-row,-rowend)